# Remove loading bar as background image in CSS using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom made loading bar. I am using it by hiding him behind the back of a photo so whenever the photo changes the background appears and when the photo was loaded the loading bar hides behind the photo.
Recently I had to use transport images and now the loading bar is visible behind the image.

The id for the photo is "generated" and this is the css.

```
#generated {
    border: 1px solid #021a40;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/loading400px.gif) 50% no-repeat;
}
```

I have a JS function that changes this image.

```
function AsynchronouslyDownloadImage(address, img) {
    img.src = "static/images/shader.svg";
    let downloadingImage = new Image();
    downloadingImage.onload = function () {
        // This img.style.background is what I thought will make my background disappear but this isn't working
        img.style.background = "";
        img.src = this.src;
    };

    downloadingImage.src = imagesEndpoint;
    }
```

Per the long comment, the ïmg.style.background is what I thought will work. 
img is a reference to an element that his id=generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 

`img.style.background = "";`

try this:

`img.style.background = "transparent";`

or perhaps you might try this:

`img.style.display = "none";`